# <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script> in dotnetcore

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

I have a .net core application. But if I try to login, I get this error:

GET http://localhost:7210/js/site.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

And of course I googled first. But script in the _layout.cshtml is standing correct:

```
<script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

And I also installed the nuget package:

BuildBundlerMinifier

But no results.

SO what I have to change ? Thank you

project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>beThere.AuthService</RootNamespace>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <DocumentationFile>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\AuthService.xml</DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Common.Vault\Common.Vault.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Common\Common.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="BuildBundlerMinifier" Version="3.2.435" />
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="JetBrains.Annotations" Version="2019.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers" Version="2.9.8">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="3.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="Pages\_ViewImports.cshtml">
      <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

like this:

```
[
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/site.min.css",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/css/site.css"
    ]
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/site.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/js/site.js"
    ],
    "minify": {
      "enabled": true,
      "renameLocals": true
    },
    "sourceMap": false
  }
]
```

Comment: Why you got your port number as 777777278810? Can you show your project file? And what folder you put your js file in?

Comment: I just edited that. oke

Comment: site.js is in wwwroot/js folder

Comment: But that file is empty

Comment: can you show the screenshot of your project folder tree?

Comment: How does the bundleconfig.json look like?

Comment: Try "rebuilding" the project. BuildBundlerMinifier does not run on every normal build